# Cordova is not recognized as an internal or extenal command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cordova, installation

When I ran the command line,

```
cordova platform add android
```

I got this error message,

> cordova is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

However, I could install the `ios`, not this android. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Given the details you have provided, I would guess that you do not have the android tools on your path.

both the `platform_tools` and `tools` directories in the android sdk must be placed on the system path.

if you need additional help, please post more details:

1. your exact error message
2. your operating system
3. your system path

[You can find complete platform installation guides in the Cordova projects documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)